# Angular: ng-show one repeating element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table, and each row is generated using `ng-repeat`. One of the columns has a refresh icon, which when clicked carries out a task. However while this task is being carried out, I'd like the icon to spin; [see here](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#spinning).

The issue I'm having is that when I click one of the icons, they all spin, rather than the one on just that row.

```
<td class="text-center">
    <i ng-hide="refreshUserSpin" ng-click="refreshUser($index, user.id)" class="fa fa-refresh pointer"></i>
    <i ng-show="refreshUserSpin" class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin "></i>
</td>
```

So in my controller, I set the `refreshUserSpin` to false:

```
app.controller('usersController', function($scope, Users) {

    $scope.refreshUserSpin = false;

    $scope.refreshUser = function(index, community_id) {

        $scope.refreshUserSpin = true;

        Users.refreshUser(community_id)
            .success(function(data) {

                $scope.users[index] = data.json;
                $scope.refreshUserSpin = false;
            });
    };

});
```

Now this sends all of the icons into a spin. What is the correct way to handle this, so it only does it for that row.

I've tried doing things like:

```
<i ng-show="refreshUserSpin.$index" class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin "></i>
```

Then doing `$scope.refreshUserSpin.index = true;`, but this didn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: As `ng-repeat` creates new scope you need to have different `refreshUserSpin` flag variable to handle each row. You can create array to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<td class="text-center">
    <i ng-hide="refreshUserSpin[$index]" ng-click="refreshUser($index, user.id)" class="fa fa-refresh pointer"></i>
    <i ng-show="refreshUserSpin[$index]" class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin "></i>
</td>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('usersController', function($scope, Users) {

    $scope.refreshUserSpin = {};

    $scope.refreshUser = function(index, community_id) {

        $scope.refreshUserSpin[index] = true;

        Users.refreshUser(community_id)
            .success(function(data) {

                $scope.users[index] = data.json;
                $scope.refreshUserSpin[index] = false;
            });
    };

});
```